# jmeter 3.2 increase latency like TC traffic control?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, latency

My question --> is there any way to increase delay in sending request and receive response in jmeter? I do not mean Timers but smth like TC Traffic control in linux. I wanna measure packages delay.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Apache HttpClient common properties](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html) reference:

> **httpclient.socket.http.cps** Set characters per second to a value greater then zero to emulate slow connections.
>
> Defaults to: 0
>
> **httpclient.socket.https.cps** Same as before but for https. Defaults to: 0

So if you want JMeter to pretend being on 10 Mbits/s network you can add the next 2 lines to *user.properties* file:

```
httpclient.socket.http.cps=1280000
httpclient.socket.https.cps=1280000
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the properties up. If you want to apply the properties without restart - you can pass them via `-J` command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jhttpclient.socket.http.cps=1280000 -Jhttpclient.socket.https.cps=1280000 -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [How to Simulate Different Network Speeds in Your JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-simulate-different-network-speeds-your-jmeter-load-test)